# hide a div after attaching it to html with the Jquery append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to hide divs that have been added to HTML, but it only works with those that are already included on the page.

I believe the problem is when clicking, because what was added does not find the function in the DOM

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cont = 1;
  $("#add-corpo").click(function() {
    cont++;
    $('<button type="button" id="btn' + cont + '" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo' + cont + '">Show / Hide</button>').appendTo("#formulario");

    $('<div class="corpo-form" id="corpo' + cont + '">Something else here...</div><hr>').appendTo("#formulario");
    $('<button type="button" id="' + cont + '" class="btn-apagar"> x </button>').appendTo("#corpo" + cont + "");
  });

  $("form").on("click", ".btn-apagar", function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('#corpo' + button_id + '').remove();
    $('#btn' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $(function() {
    $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
      alert("It is working");
      e.preventDefault();
      el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="corpo">
  <form id="add-pub" method="POST" action="insert_rot.php">
    <div id="formulario">
      <button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo1">
Show / Hide</button>
      <div class="corpo-form" id="corpo1">
        Something else here ...
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="botoes">
      <button type="button" id="add-corpo"> + </button>
      <input type="submit" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="
Publish">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could someone help me solve this problem and find out what it really is?

thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.click` for your show hide button. Which will only hit items on loaded in page.

Use `$("#corpo").on('click',` to apply this click event to newly added items. Like this for example...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cont = 1;
  $("#add-corpo").click(function() {
    cont++;
    $('<button type="button" id="btn' + cont + '" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo' + cont + '">Show / Hide</button>').appendTo("#formulario");

    $('<div class="corpo-form" id="corpo' + cont + '">Something else here...</div><hr>').appendTo("#formulario");
    $('<button type="button" id="' + cont + '" class="btn-apagar"> x </button>').appendTo("#corpo" + cont + "");
  });

  $("form").on("click", ".btn-apagar", function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('#corpo' + button_id + '').remove();
    $('#btn' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#corpo").on('click', '.btn-toggle', function(e) {
      alert("It is working");
      e.preventDefault();
      el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="corpo">
  <form id="add-pub" method="POST" action="insert_rot.php">
    <div id="formulario">
      <button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo1">
Show / Hide</button>
      <div class="corpo-form" id="corpo1">
        Something else here ...
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="botoes">
      <button type="button" id="add-corpo"> + </button>
      <input type="submit" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="
Publish">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!! :)

Comment: @LucasMachado no worries can you mark as solved to close the question if this solves your problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

`.click` Method is initialize on page loaded or (DOM Ready). If there is append any new element inside body then `.click` method will not recognize where it is because of this is already loaded in DOM so you need to use `$(document).on('click', '.btn-toggle',  function(){...});` or replace `document` with `parent element` of append element.
You need to remove `<hr>` also like `$('#line' + button_id + '').remove();`.
Source: https://api.jquery.com/click/ 
I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cont = 1;
    $("#add-corpo").click(function () {
        cont++;
        $('<button type="button" id="btn' + cont + '" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo' + cont + '">Show / Hide</button>').appendTo("#formulario");
        $('<div class="corpo-form" id="corpo' + cont + '">Something else here...</div><hr id="line'+cont+'">').appendTo("#formulario");
        $('<button type="button" id="' + cont + '" class="btn-apagar"> x </button>').appendTo("#corpo" + cont + "");
    });

    $("form").on("click", ".btn-apagar", function () {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#corpo' + button_id + '').remove();
        $('#line' + button_id + '').remove();
        $('#btn' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

    $("form").on("click", ".btn-toggle", function (e) {
        alert("It is working");
        e.preventDefault();
        el = $(this).data('element');
        $(el).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="corpo">
    <form id="add-pub" method="POST" action="insert_rot.php">
        <div id="formulario">
            <button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#corpo1">
                Show / Hide</button>
            <div class="corpo-form" id="corpo1">
                Something else here ...
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="botoes">
            <button type="button" id="add-corpo"> + </button>
            <input type="submit" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="Publish">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! Now I could understand what happened. Helped me a lot! :))